# Fetching from the root '/' route seems to not work?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a very simple server in expressjs from which I'll be getting some data, so far I just created basic routes and checked if they work, but I have an issue with the main '/' one. I added some extra routes for comparison

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('request at /');
})
app.get('/ree1', (req, res) => {
    console.log('ree1');
})
app.get('/ree2', (req, res) => {
    console.log('ree2')
})
app.get('/ree3', (req, res) => {
    console.log('ree3')
})
```

Every time I fetch (from the browser console even) all the "/ree" routes log in the console, but the '/' one doesn't react at all. What could be the cause of that? Perhaps I missed something when I was learning basics.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Tried it myself. How are you hitting the root("/") endpoint? Also, log statements will be visible at the server-side, not the browser. Another thing, you've "request at /" in the log statement which is different from all the other log statements. I hope you know that.

Comment: @KartikChauhan At the moment I'm just using fetch() in the browser, the ultimate goal is for my reactJS app to communicate with that server later. I'm aware of all the things you listed, the thing is "fetch('/')" just doesn't log anything, while other routes do, I added them just to showcase the issue, seems like I can basically add infinite amount of routes and they'll work, just '/' doesn't for some reason

Comment: Please add the necessary code if someone wants to reproduce the issue. Because the code-snippet you posted has nothing wrong with it.